# firebase add data to database with array

Tags: arrays, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a set of data to a database by pushing the data to an array and adding them to the database. I have added my codes here

```
const com = {

      company: "Com",
      description: "Turn ...",
      pointsNeeded: "500",
      title: "Com",
      PromoCode: Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000000),
      imageLocation: "www...",
      

  }

  this.afDB.list('rewards/' + se.uid).push(com)
    .then(next => {
      console.log(next);
    });
```

This is how my database look like
[image]

However, I would like the database to be like

```
 "rewards" : {
"fH7GPHMFupW2JD8fxKnLOvHBZ0w1" : {
    0: {
      "PromoCode" : 
      "company" : 
      "description" : 
      "imageLocation" : 
      "pointsNeeded" : 
      "title" : 
    },
    1" : {
      "PromoCode" : 
      "company" : 
      "description" : 
      "imageLocation" :
      "pointsNeeded" : 
      "title" : 
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone advice? I am not really sure what to do next.
Thanks

UPDATE:

```
 const getUserReward = firebase.database().ref('rewards/').child(se.uid)
  getUserReward.once('value', data => {
    
    var rewardArray =[];
    rewardArray.push(comchestReward)
    getUserReward.update({rewards: rewardArray})
  })
```

So this is the code I have so far but it is now

[image]

Comment: Firestore Realtime Database doesn't work well with integer indexed arrays like this.  In fact, what you're trying to do is an anti-pattern.  You should keep using push() instead.  I suggest reading this for help understanding best practices for arrays: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: hi may i know what you mean by anti pattern and keep using push() instead?